# Python automatically closing

Tags: python

Can someone tell me why when I open this python file it automatically closes?

```
import itertools   

for combination in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=4):
    print ''.join(map(str, combination))
    with open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(join(map(str, combination)))
```

fixed indentation

Comment: What is the error message that it gives you? Also, the last line should be indented one more level.

Comment: fix the indentation for the last line.

Comment: I can't give you the error message because there's not much time to even see it, I see the console for a split second before it closes.

Comment: I advise you open python file in command line or bash instead of double clicking so that the error msg will be displayed and stayed at screen

Comment: you can always open the command line (on windows, win+R then type `cmd`), navigate to the folder you have your script in and type `python myscript.py`. The window should stay open even if the script aborts.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "com.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt", "a") as myfile:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('a') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\test.txt'

Comment: Change your open to this: open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.txt", "a")

Comment: I now receive this: 0000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "com.py", line 6, in <module>
    myfile.write(join(map(str, combination)))
NameError: name 'join' is not defined

Comment: should be `myfile.write("".join(map(str, combination)))`

Comment: I now receive this error:   File "com.py", line 6
    myfile.write("".join(map(str, combination)))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: did you indent the last line one more time to the right, as I said in my first comment?

Comment: yes I did that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153207/discussion-between-honza-zika-and-l746577).

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you are using the `with` style of opening files. The file closes when you exit the `with` block. Its a safe way of opening files. That way you don't have to explicity call the `close` method on `myfile`. To avoid this you can use

```
myfile = open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.txt", "a")
myfile.write(join(map(str, combination)))
```

Note that once you are done using the file make sure you use `myfile.close()`

You can go through [this page](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) for details

**EDIT**

Try using this

```
import itertools
with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    for combination in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=4):
        print (''.join(map(str, combination)))
        myfile.write(''.join(map(str, combination)))
```

Comment: It still closes instantly.

Comment: Hi, I'm receiving this error? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "com.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt", "a") as myfile:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('a') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\test.txt'

Comment: the error is explanatory. Use a different mode for the file. Try using 'w' or 'r'

Comment: have you used `import itertools` at the top

Comment: I'm now getting this error: 0000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "com.py", line 6, in <module>
    myfile.write(join(map(str, combination)))
NameError: name 'join' is not defined

Comment: you need to use something like `' '.join(list)`. Check out the usage of join.

Comment: I now receive this error:   File "com.py", line 6
    myfile.write("".join(map(str, combination)))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Thats beacuse your indentation is broken. Fix that

Answer (score 0):

About 'with' commands: [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Short description: They close your file, after the end of the block execution even if you forget to close it yourself. Its a nicer way to put your code, instead of try-finally.

In your case, it opens once for each iteration of the loop. And closes at the end. Then, opens it for the next iteration again. That is inefficient.

Just a suggestion, you want to avoid opening the file inside your `for` loop.
You could call it outside, so that it is opened once, and then you run the loop. The `with` statement will automatically close the file at the end of the block execution. But again, depends on your context of use.

```
with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    for combination in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=4):
        print ''.join(map(str, combination))
        myfile.write(''.join(map(str, combination)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

for combination in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=4):
    print ''.join(map(str, combination))
    with open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(join(map(str, combination)))
```

now it will work. `with` will create a block, so you need to indent. Keep in mind:)

Answer (score 0):

For your reference see this article [Python 'with' keyword](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)

When we open a file using `with` keyword, then we need not to close that explicitly. Also this is the `best practice` to do file handling.

Also fix indentation of last line of your code

Comment: But this requires an extra indentation block, which is annoying, e.g. much neater to write `return [line for line in open("file.txt")]`

Answer (score 0):

You should also modify the last line into:

`myfile.write(''.join(map(str, combination)))`

And reference @RetardedJoker's answer

Here is my code:

```
import itertools

with open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    for combination in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=4):
        result = ''.join(map(str, combination))
        print result
        myfile.write(result)
```